# What happens if an ISR hangs in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

If an ISR hangs for some reason, e.g. waiting for a spinlock, or a never ending loop, how does Linux recover from this ?

Comment: No recovery actions are taken in such cases. That is, Linux itself may hang because of incorrect ISR.

Comment: NMI is only possible recovery, though it's being used mostly for debugging or emergency cases after them it would die.

Comment: if ISR hangs your almost screwed up. Troubleshooting from there bit tedious work not straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are stuck in ISR by some reason then it would be difficult to take out system from this state. You would get kernel stack traces after equal interval of time, however it would be not possible to say that system would recover from this state ever. We may need to restart even in worst case.

The kernel trace would be similar to this one:

`[ 1872.084006] CPU: 0 PID: 5585 Comm: insmod Tainted: G           OEL  4.4.0-78-generic #99~14.04.2-Ubuntu
    [ 1872.084006] Hardware name: LENOVO 2847DJU/2847DJU, BIOS 6JET85WW (1.43 ) 12/24/2010
    [ 1872.084006] task: ffff880117d94e00 ti: ffff88004a654000 task.ti: ffff88004a654000
    [ 1872.084006] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc0008019>]  [<ffffffffc0008019>] sample_init+0x19/0x1000 [sample]
    [ 1872.084006] RSP: 0018:ffff88004a657cc0  EFLAGS: 00000292
    [ 1872.084006] RAX: 0000000000000020 RBX: ffffffff81e13080 RCX: 0000000000000006
    [ 1872.084006] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000246 RDI: ffff88013fc0dd90
    [ 1872.084006] RBP: ffff88004a657cc0 R08: 000000000000000a R09: 0000000000000000
    [ 1872.084006] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 000000000000047c R12: ffff88003a50ffe0
    [ 1872.084006] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffffffc0008000 R15: ffff88004a657eb0
    [ 1872.084006] FS:  00007f53c147b740(0000) GS:ffff88013fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
    [ 1872.084006] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
    [ 1872.084006] CR2: ffffffffc0007fee CR3: 000000004a530000 CR4: 00000000000406f0
    [ 1872.084006] Stack:
    [ 1872.084006]  ffff88004a657d38 ffffffff8100213d ffff88004a657eb0 ffff88004a657d10
    [ 1872.084006]  0000000000000246 0000000000000002 ffffffff811deafd ffff88013b401c00
    [ 1872.084006]  ffffffff81183ca4 0000000000000018 00000000f91cc401 ffffffffc06f3000
    [ 1872.084006] Call Trace:
    [ 1872.084006]  [<ffffffff8100213d>] do_one_initcall+0xcd/0x1f0
    [ 1872.084006]  [<ffffffff811deafd>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x1ad/0x220
    [ 1872.084006]  [<ffffffff81183ca4>] ? do_init_module+0x27/0x1d2
    [ 1872.084006]  [<ffffffff81183cdd>] do_init_module+0x60/0x1d2
    [ 1872.084006]  [<ffffffff81104134>] load_module+0x1424/0x1b10
    [ 1872.084006]  [<ffffffff81100920>] ? __symbol_put+0x40/0x40
    [ 1872.084006]  [<ffffffff81206be1>] ? kernel_read+0x41/0x60
    [ 1872.084006]  [<ffffffff811049ee>] SYSC_finit_module+0x7e/0xa0
    [ 1872.084006]  [<ffffffff81104a2e>] SyS_finit_module+0xe/0x10
    [ 1872.084006]  [<ffffffff8180b776>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
    [ 1872.084006] Code: <eb> fe 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
    [ 1884.688004] INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
    [ 1884.688004]  0-...: (105006 ticks this GP) idle=41d/140000000000001/0 softirq=64742/64742 fqs=104241 
    [ 1884.688004]   (t=105006 jiffies g=35345 c=35344 q=27697)
    [ 1884.688004] Task dump for CPU 0:
    [ 1884.688004] insmod          R  running task        0  5585   1990 0x0000000c
    [ 1884.688004]  ffffffff81e55040 ffff88013fc03db8 ffffffff810ab14f 0000000000000000
    [ 1884.688004]  ffffffff81e55040 ffff88013fc03dd0 ffffffff810ad8b9 0000000000000001
    [ 1884.688004]  ffff88013fc03e00 ffffffff810dff6a ffff88013fc17b80 ffffffff81e55040
    [ 1884.688004] Call Trace:
    [ 1884.688004]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff810ab14f>] sched_show_task+0xaf/0x110
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff810ad8b9>] dump_cpu_task+0x39/0x40
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff810dff6a>] rcu_dump_cpu_stacks+0x8a/0xc0
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff810e3a93>] rcu_check_callbacks+0x4b3/0x7a0
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff810ae361>] ? account_system_time+0x81/0x110
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff810ae600>] ? account_process_tick+0x60/0x170
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff810f9200>] ? tick_sched_do_timer+0x30/0x30
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff810e9b79>] update_process_times+0x39/0x60
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff810f8c05>] tick_sched_handle.isra.15+0x25/0x60
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff810f923d>] tick_sched_timer+0x3d/0x70
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff810ea6d3>] __hrtimer_run_queues+0xf3/0x260
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff810eab78>] hrtimer_interrupt+0xa8/0x1a0
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffffc0008000>] ? 0xffffffffc0008000
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff81050ec5>] local_apic_timer_interrupt+0x35/0x60
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff8180e21d>] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x3d/0x50
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff8180c4e2>] apic_timer_interrupt+0x82/0x90
    [ 1884.688004]  <EOI>  [<ffffffffc0008000>] ? 0xffffffffc0008000
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffffc0008019>] ? sample_init+0x19/0x1000 [sample]
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff8100213d>] do_one_initcall+0xcd/0x1f0
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff811deafd>] ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x1ad/0x220
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff81183ca4>] ? do_init_module+0x27/0x1d2
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff81183cdd>] do_init_module+0x60/0x1d2
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff81104134>] load_module+0x1424/0x1b10
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff81100920>] ? __symbol_put+0x40/0x40
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff81206be1>] ? kernel_read+0x41/0x60
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff811049ee>] SYSC_finit_module+0x7e/0xa0
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff81104a2e>] SyS_finit_module+0xe/0x10
    [ 1884.688004]  [<ffffffff8180b776>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75`

Comment: What about nmi watchdog? http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v2.6.32/source/Documentation/nmi_watchdog.txt "if any CPU in the system does not
execute the period local timer interrupt for more than 5 seconds, then
the NMI handler generates an oops and kills the process", sysctl kernel.nmi_watchdog

Comment: Thanks for answer . By the way, what would happen if an ISR tries to accquire a mutex that is unavailable ? How does Linux respond then ?

Comment: ISR can't sleep, it can't acquire mutex.

Comment: @osgx, is it blast from the past? Try another version and tell us what you found.

Comment: @0andriy, It is not: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/stable/kernel/watchdog.c#228 https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/lockup-watchdogs.txt "Softlockup detector and hardlockup detector (aka nmi_watchdog)" "An NMI perf event is generated every"

Comment: @osgx: It doesn't make sense in terms of real hardware ISR issues. And also it is not useful on other platforms like ARM, where most of the embedded world exists.

Comment: @osgx, it does not say anything about recovery, but says about debugging, what I told early.